# How to build Boost.Test dynamic library and link it to my project in CMake?

Tags: boost, cmake, boost-test

What I did:

I built the library as described [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/adv_scenarios/build_utf.html):

```
> cd $boost_path
> bootstrap.bat
> b2 address-model=64 architecture=x86 --with-test link=shared --prefix=$boost_installation_prefix install
```

My $boost_path is P:\boost_1_65_1 and $boost_installation_prefix is a folder called boosttest in P:\boost_1_65_1

And then in my cmake I try to find it as follows:

```
project(Test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8 FATAL_ERROR)

# Get Boost
set(BOOST_ROOT "P:/boost_1_65_1") 
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)
```

But CMake simply says:
Could NOT find Boost

What am I doing wrong? I suspect I am building the library in the wrong location, but then where do I put it?

Comment: `BOOST_ROOT` should refer to the **installation prefix** of the Boost, not to its build directory.

Comment: Great, now I feel like a complete idiot.